# Detect if role instance exists in windows azure

Tags: azure

Is there a service inside windows azure that I can query a non cached record of role instances to see if a role instance exists, and if it exists, what is its IP address and port?

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's possible from within your cloud service:

```
foreach (var role in Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.Roles)
{
    foreach (var instance in role.Value.Instances)
    {
        foreach (string endpointName in instance.InstanceEndpoints.Keys)
        {
            RoleInstanceEndpoint endpoint = instance.InstanceEndpoints[endpointName];
            IPEndPoint ipEndpoint = endpoint.IPEndpoint;                        
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to do it from outside your cloud service you'll need to work with the Service Management API: *The [Get Deployment operation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460804.aspx) returns configuration information, status, and system properties for a deployment.*

Comment: Is Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.Roles a cached list?  From my understand this value is cached and is polled every couple of minutes.  So in theory a role instance can get created, do some work and other role instances will still believe that the role instance hasn't even started.  That wouldn't be an ideal situation for me.  I am looking for an entry that would record the existence of an instance before it is loaded into the load balancer.